# Send a chart/sparkline through Google Chat App

Tags: chatbot, google-chat, py-appscript

I created a Google Chat Bot (using Google Appscript) to take in user query (a metric) to look up the data that I have in Google Sheet. Whenever the user asks for a particular metric, the bot goes through the data and replies with the current value. I have a sparkline next to the metric, and also have a chart that shows the trend (see image below). I want to know if there's a possibility to send the chart/sparkline (in this order of preference) along with the bot's response. And if yes, could you please show me how to do this?

[image]

Thank you

Send chart/sparkline along with the bot's response.

Comment: The functionality would be a long stretch, since you would need to use Spreadsheet Service, Google Charts API (to build the sparkline), Drive Service coincidentally with Chat Bot for this to work.